# VueJS Custom Directive Function as Argument

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a simple directive:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-sample:callback="greet"></div>
</div>
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      files: [],
    },
    methods: {
      greet: function (arg) {
        alert(arg);
      },
    },
  });
</script>
```

JS:

```
Vue.directive('sample', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('...', function () {
      // ...
      callback.call(arg, ...);
    });
  },
});
```

However, I'm unclear of the appropriate syntax to get the function and evaluate. What's the proper way to do this from within a directive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `binding.value` which should be a function in this case. It's already prebound to correct context so just call it (pass anything in it if you need something):

```
Vue.directive('sample', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
      binding.value()
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: What happened to the word "callback" here? Is it ignored?

Comment: To answer my own question: per the docs, the string 'callback' should appear as `binding.arg`: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html Directives sure give you a lot of ways to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Working on Nuxt3 + Vue3

```js
    // Run this module from some defineNuxtPlugin config (client only)
    export default (vueInstance) => {
      
      // Click outside some element
      vueInstance.directive('click-outside', {
        created(el, binding, vnode, prevVnode) {
          el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
            console.log(binding.instance.close)
            if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
              if(binding.instance[binding.value]) {
                binding.instance[binding.value](event)
              }
            }
          }
    
          document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
        },
        beforeUnmount(el, binding, vnode, prevVnode) {
          document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
        }
      })
    
    }
```

```html
<div v-click-outside="'close'">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do like this.

```
<div v-mydirect:fn="params"></div>

Vue.directive('mydirect', {
    bind (el, binding,vnode) {
        let that = vnode.context
        that[binding.arg](binding.value)
    }
})
```